# How to simplify $\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot k!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, induction, factorial

How do I go about simplifying this:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk \cdot k!$$

Wolfram alpha tells me it's the same as $(n+1)!-1$ but I don't see how.

Comment: If true it must follow by induction.

Answer (score 14):

Hint: $$k\cdot k! = [(k+1)-1]\cdot k! = (k+1)!-k!$$